# Derivative at $x=0$ for $\frac{1}{x\ln(2)} - \frac{1}{2^x - 1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> A function $f$ is defined on $\Bbb R$ as $\frac{1}{x\ln 2 } - \frac{1}{2^x  -1}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ for $x = 0$. Show that $f$ is continuous and find $f'(0)$

From my knowledge

$$f'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}\\
 =\frac{\frac{1}{x\ln(2)} - \frac{1}{2^x-1} - \frac{1}{2}}{x}\\
 = \frac{\frac{x \ln(2)}{2(2^x-1)} - \frac{1}{2}}{x}\\
 = \frac{x \ln(2) - (2^x -1)}{2x(2^x - 1)}\\
 = \frac{x^2 \ln^2(2)}{4x(2^x - 1)}$$

Which on using mclaurin series of $2^x$ gives $\frac{-\ln 2}{4}$ but the correct answer is $\frac{-\ln 2}{12}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\frac{1}{x\ln(2)}-\frac{1}{2^x-1}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{(2^x-1)2-2x\ln(2)-(2^x-1)x\ln(2)}{x\ln(2)(2^x-1)\cdot 2}$$

Comment: What after this Dr Sonnhard?

Comment: You must divide by $x$ and discover if the limit for $x$ tends to zero exists.

Comment: Are you sure that you have made do typo?

Comment: I think this limit doesn't exist.

Comment: why? please tell me the answer is given as -pi/12 only, but there is option that it doesnt exist

Comment: Ok the serarched limit is $$-\frac{1}{12}\ln(2)$$!!!

Answer (score 1):

You did not include all terms in the series. In intermediate steps, there is also a term $\frac{x^3\ln^3(2)}{3!}$ which is missed.

$$\frac{\frac{1}{x\ln(2)} - \frac{1}{2^x-1} - \frac{1}{2}}{x} = \frac{2(2^{x}-1)-2(x \ln(2))-x\ln(2)(2^{x}-1)}{2x^2 \ln(2)(2^{x}-1)} \\
 = \frac{2(x\ln(2)+\tfrac{x^2 \ln^2(2)}{2}+\tfrac{x^3 \ln^3(2)}{6})-2x\ln 2 - x \ln(2)(x\ln(2)+\tfrac{x^2 \ln^2(2)}{2})}{2x^2 \ln(2)(2^{x}-1)}\\
 = \frac{-\tfrac{x^3 \ln^3(2)}{6}}{2x^2 \ln(2)(2^{x}-1)}$$

which will give $ \frac{-\ln(2)}{12}$ as the limit.

Comment: I am  not sure I get you, I used only mclaurin as you did, it didn't require to go to x^3

Comment: see, in intermediate steps, you did use $2^x - 1 = ...$ but only upto 2 terms. The problem is that the next term also contributes to limit, which you neglected.